# About perpendicular vectors

Tags: vectors

I am studying the ortogonal vectors. And i see the geometrical view of it as they are perpendicular vectors.   I see zero  vector is orthogonal to every vector ie zero vector is perpendicular to each vector. But how geometrically zero vector is perpendicular to each vector,where is an angle of 90° between zero vector and other vectors. OR how we define an angle between zero vector and any other vector.????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no definition for the angle between the zero vector and another (at least, no reasonable definition).

In fact, there is a subtle difference between the usage of the terms "orthogonal" and "perpendicular".  Two vectors are orthogonal if their dot product is zero, no matter what.  Only non-zero vectors can be perpendicular. So, in the usual usage, the zero-vector is orthogonal but not perpendicular to all other vectors.

Comment: It means that we can say every perpendicular vectors are orthogonal but every orthogonal vectors are not perpendicular.

Comment: "Every pair of perpendicular vectors are orthogonal, but not every pair of orthogonal vectors is perpendicular".  That's right.

Answer (score 0):

Orthogonality occurs with dot product zero, while being perpendicular is implied by orthogonality, but is defined for nonzero vectors.

So yes, the zero vector is orthogonal to all nonzero vectors, but not perpendicular, because that doesn't make sense.